# Configuring Scala Debugger for Scala IDE

Tags: scala, scala-ide

I'm trying to configure [Scala Debuger](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/features/scaladebugger/index.html).

I have `specs2` tests:

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class DictionaryTest extends Specification  { ...
```

> 1. I've downloaded preconfigured default `scala-ide`.
> 2. Turn on scala debugger by default like was said on the [image](http://scala-ide.org/docs/_images/preferences-012.png) (2nd slide). Restart eclipse.
> 3. Put breakpoint in my `specs2 tests`, but when start debugger still see **java-like** stack-traces when the code reaches the breakpoint (not like on [3rd slide](http://scala-ide.org/docs/_images/scaladisplay-012.png)).

**Q:** Are there some addition steps I should perform to start using/testing`scala-debugger` ?

Edit: why my screen is different than doc's screenshot. It seems Scala debugger was not On? **At least I was hoping to see word 'Scala Display'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, your probably hit a known limitation. Currently, the new debugger is available for the Scala launcher, but **not** for the JUnit launcher. Here is the [relevant ticket](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1001635#/activity/ticket%3a).

You could work around it if you configured the test runner to wait for a remote debugger connection, and then connect the scala debugger as described [here](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/features/scaladebugger/index.html)